# Feature Pyramid Network with tensorflow/models/object_detection

Tags: tensorflow, classification, feature-extraction, object-detection

If I want to implement k = k0 + log2(√(w*h)/224) in *Feature Pyramid Networks for Object Detection*, where and which file should I change?

Note, this formula is for ROI pooling. W and H are the width and height of ROI, whereas k represents the level of the feature pyramid this ROI should be used on.

*saying the FasterRCNN meta_architecture file of in object_detection might be helpful, but please inform me which method I can change.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this document](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md) for a rough overview of the process. In a nutshell, you'll have to create a "FeatureExtractor" sub-class for you desired meta-architecture. For FasterRCNN, you can probably start with a copy of our [Resnet101 Feature Extractor](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/models/faster_rcnn_resnet_v1_feature_extractor.py) as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. So is there any possible changes I can make in faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py? Since I saw many methods that control the first stage and second stage. In the meantime, I have already changed the Resnet101 Feature Extractor (return variable has changed from a single layer resnet to a dictionary that contains the whole pyramid). I really want to know where I can put this formula into practice.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the change won't be trivial as we don't currently support cropping regions from multiple layers.  Here is an outline of what would need to change if you would like to pursue this anyway:

- Generating a new anchor set
  Currently Faster RCNN uses a “GridAnchorGenerator” as the first_stage_anchor_generator - instead you will have to use a MultipleGridAnchorGenerator (same as we use in SSD pipeline).
- You will have to use a 32^2 anchor box -> for the scales field of the anchor generator, basically you will have to add a .125
- You will have to modify the code to generate and crop from multiple layers: to start, look for a function in the faster_rcnn_meta_arch file called "_extract_rpn_feature_maps", which is suggestively named, but currently returns just a single tensor!  You will also have to add some logic to determine which layer to crop from based on the size of the proposal (Eqn 1 from the paper)
- You will have to finally create a new feature extractor following the [directions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md) that Derek linked to.

Comment: Thank you so much for this note! I was about to finish FPN. Only a few minor bugs (regarding the batches and dimensions) left for solving.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, could you elaborate on the .125, and MultipleGridAnchorGenerator? 
box_specs_list=[[(2.0, 0.5), (2.0, 1.0), (2.0, 2.0)],  # P2
                          [(1.0, 0.5), (1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 2.0)],  # P3
                          [(0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 1.0), (0.5, 2.0)],  # P4
                          [(0.25, 0.5), (0.25, 1.0), (0.25, 2.0)],  # P5
                          [(0.125, 0.5), (0.125, 1.0), (0.125, 2.0)]], # P6 

Would something like this make sense? Some implementations use scales of 8...